# How to check if h(n) is causal, stable?

Tags: filters, stability, causality

I have $x(n)$ = {$4,-1,-3,1$} and $h(n)$ = {$2,1,3,5$}.

I would like to know how can I check whether

$h(n)$ is stable filter or not and 
$h(n)$ is causal filter or not?

Comment: hey! Your notation isn't quite right, and that makes it impossible for you to answer this yourself :) $h(n)$ is a *single value*, the value of the signal (or impulse response) $h$ at time $n$. Now, $\{2,1,3,5\}$ is a set of values, and that's not what you wanted. So, first step, figure out for which $n$ the value of $h$ becomes $2$, for which it becomes $1$ and so on. Then check the definition of "causal"!

Comment: let say h(n = 0) = 2, h(n = 1) = 1, h(n = 2) = 3, h(n = 3) = 5.

Comment: if you say so, congratulations, you've just answered your own causality question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, you do not need to specify an input $x(n)$ to know whether the system is stable or causal, these are properties of the system itslef, I will interpret $h(n)$ you mention as a array describing the system response.

For causality in time domain perspectivefor an LTI system check if $h(n) =0 $ for all $n < 0$, that is the $h(n)$ is essentially a right sided sequence.

For causality in Z domain perspective equivalently, the Region of Convergence is the right side of the outermost pole (outermost in terms of the highest magnitude pole in z domain)

For stability in time domain perspective, the system response $h(n)$ should be absolutely summable, since you have only finite coefficients, this system is stable, any FIR filter is always stable.

For stability from Z domain perspective, the region of Convergence must contain the unit circle.

For stable and causal system all these conditions hold at the same time.